# Why can't I see the email address from contact form?

Tags: php, html, forms, email, contacts

I receive an email but it will read from unknown. Everything else seems to work. Here is a link to the page [link](http://podmtg.com/contact.html) I don't know much about php.

```
    <?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $mailTo = "contact@podmtg.com";
    $headers = "From: ".$mailFrom;
    $txt = "You have recieved an email from ".$name.".\n\n".$message;

    mail($mailTo, $subject, $txt, $headers);

    header("Location: contact.html?mailsend");
}

?>

<form action="contactform.php" method="post" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit this form?');">
             <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required="required">
             <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="required">
             <textarea name="message" placeholder="Write message here..." required="required"></textarea>
             <button type="submit" name="submit">SUBMIT</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: `$email` != `$mailFrom`

Comment: $email has the email address but you are trying to read from $emailFrom. I am wondering why it is not throwing exception.

Comment: $mailFrom is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

In this you have mention this `$headers = "From: ".$mailFrom; but not $mailFrom found. Use $email  in place of $mailFrom.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code. You guys were right. Thank you!

```
    <?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $mailFrom = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $mailTo = "contact@podmtg.com";
    $headers = "From: ".$mailFrom;
    $txt = "You have recieved an email from ".$name.".\n\n".$message;

    mail($mailTo, $headers, $txt);

    header("Location: index.html?mailsend");
}

?>
```